# Pause in beamer in the middle of an infer from the proof package

Tags: beamer, proof-package

I have this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{proof}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  \[
    \infer{\textrm{conclusion}}
    {
      \infer{\textrm{intermediate conclusion}}
      {\textrm{premises}}
      &
      \infer{\textrm{other conclusion}}
      {\textrm{other premises}}
    }
  \]
}
\end{document}
```

which produces a frame with
[image]

I would like to show first "other premises", then add "other conclusion", then "premises", then "intermediate conclusion" and finally the whole thing. However, I cannot use `pause` since the order in the code is at the inverse, and I tried in several ways with `\onslide+<2->`, which did not work either.

Any help?

**Clarification:** I would prefer that the lines when there are not yet introduced the premises/conclusions, do not appear. They should appear in order as they are needed. For example, first only the sentence "other premises" should appear, then when "other conclusion" appears, just then the line between them should be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{proof}

\begin{document}
\frame{
  \[
    \color{white}
    \color<5->{black}{
      \infer{\textrm{conclusion}}
      {
        {\color<4->{black}
          \infer{\textrm{intermediate conclusion}}
          {\color<3->{black}\textrm{premises}}
        }
        &
        {\color<2->{black}
        \infer{\textrm{other conclusion}}
        {\color{black}\textrm{other premises}}
      }
    }
  }
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{proof}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  \[
    \infer{\textrm{conclusion}}
    {
      \infer{\visible<5->{\textrm{intermediate conclusion}}}
      {\visible<4->{\textrm{premises}}}
      &
      \infer{\visible<3->{\textrm{other conclusion}}}
      {\visible<2->{\textrm{other premises}}}
    }
  \]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! I would prefer that the lines do not appear until they are needed, but this solution is already acceptable for what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroDC I have no idea about the syntax of the `\infer` command, but you could try to wrap it inside a `\visible` command.

Comment: Morally, what I need is that a `\visible<2->` contains a `\visible<1->`. Do you know if that can be done?

Comment: @AlejandroDC Why not just try it?

Comment: Sorry, the question is "do you know if there is a way to do it?". I tried naively with `\visible<2->{\visible<1->{bla} ble}` and bla appears only in the second slide, together with ble.